# I am getting $H(1/8,7/8) = 0.16$ while the solution says $H(1/8,7/8) = 0.544$ bits

Tags: information-theory, entropy

[image: Example and solution]

Looking at the table in the picture above,

$$ H(1/8 , 7/8) = -\sum_x p(x) \log(p(x)) = - \left[ (1/8) \log(1/8) + (7/8) \log (7/8) \right] = 0.16 $$

What am i doing wrong? I can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Your entropy is in base 10, while that of the solution is in base 2. I.e., dividing your answer by $\log_{10}2$ will yield the same value as in the solution.

Comment: Thank you!! i thought my calculator 'log' as base2 automatically but obviously it is base 10

Comment: should I use base 2 when it says 'p(x)log(p(x))'  as in p(x)log2(p(x)), or log10(p(x))?

Comment: That I am not sure. One obvious solution is to clarify which log is used, like what the solution did by writing the unit 'bits'.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you clarify one more thing, in this example (https://gyazo.com/7c2690c532540f9db002274df13806fc) I think the answer H(X,Y) = -1/2 * log(1/2) - 1/4 *log(1/4) is correct, however the solution says -1/2 * log(1 / 1/2) etc. - the p(x) is written as a fraction under 1? - Should he not get rid of the negative sign because he has put the "1/4" under the fraction?

Comment: You are right, we do not need negative sign, given that it is already taken care of by reciprocals inside logs. I would jokingly say that you can glimpse the poor quality of the solution also from the mixed fraction in the final step.